# Problema con la configuración de composer.json ; al poner el siguiente código en Windows PowerShell : composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer

Este fué el Error

```
  Using version ^0.8.6 for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.8.6 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.8.6].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.6 requires illuminate/support ^5.5|^6|^7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.4.36, required as 5.4.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Y este es el fichero composer.json
{
    "name": "com/gest",
    "description": "Facturación OnLine de GESTOR",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
        "doctrine/inflector": "1.1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "^0.16.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\": "app/",
            "Tests\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error plantea la solución de forma clara:

> barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.6 requires illuminate/support ^5.5|^6|^7

En otras palabras, si deseas trabajar con la versión 0.8.6 de este paquete, deberas tener al menos Laravel 5.5.x, actualmente tienes 5.4.x

Si definitivamente DEBES trabajar con Laravel 5.4.x, entonces instala la versión 0.8.2 de barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: Perfecto,gracias envio la respuesta a instalar versión 0.8.2 >Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
The compiled services file has been removed.